# Non-scrolling image needs relatively placed trigger and brake

Tags: javascript, scroll

Here...

http://www.allaboutvision.com/test/SWIM-ryan2.htm

...I have a non-scrolling ad in the right-hand column.  It works great, but I need a couple more tweaks.

First, the stop-scroll action begins at an absolute pixel amount from the top of the page.  Instead, I need that action to begin at an absolute pixel amount below the previous div, which has the id of "relProd".  I don't know how to specify that in the javascript.

Secondly, I need the image to begin scrolling again at a fixed pixel amount above the orange ad at the bottom of the page.  (In other words, it needs to "brake" at a certain point so it doesn't cover up the orange ad.)

Can anyone help me?  I've searched everywhere for the answer.  Wish I knew more javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best that you read this [Get X Y position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) so that you can get the position of an element on the screen then just set a function `onscroll` which will run every time a user scrolls up/down

Something like this:

```
window.onscroll = function(e){
    if(in this position){
        //do this
    }else if(in this position){
        //do this
    }
}
```